# MCOConnectionLogTypeErrorParse

Tags: mailcore2

What is the cause of MCOConnectionLogTypeErrorParse ?Command to send the QUIT to return to this mistake。

> 2015-07-15 11:38:23.501 xxxxxxxxxxx[1588:845458] type==>1
>
> 2015-07-15 11:38:23.502 xxxxxxxxxxx[1588:845458] data==>QUIT
>
> 2015-07-15 11:38:23.502 xxxxxxxxxxx[1588:845458] type==>-1
>
> 2015-07-15 11:38:23.502 xxxxxxxxxxx[1588:845458] data==>
>
> 2015-07-15 11:38:23.502 xxxxxxxxxxx[1588:845458] type==>-1
>
> 2015-07-15 11:38:23.503 xxxxxxxxxxx[1588:845458] data==>
>
> 2015-07-15 11:38:53.505 xxxxxxxxxxx[1588:845458] type==>4
>
> 2015-07-15 11:38:53.506 xxxxxxxxxxx[1588:845458] data==>
>
> 2015-07-15 11:38:53.514 xxxxxxxxxxx[1588:839802] 邮件发送失败错误:Error
>   Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could
>   not be established." UserInfo=0x17426bb80 {NSLocalizedDescription=A
>   stable connection to the server could not be established.}

But in fact is sent successfully

Comment: Can you show the connectionLogger log of the full session here?

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong should be MCOConnectionLogTypeErrorReceived

Comment: Is it because the default timeout is 30 seconds？And type -1 is what type